# Trigger Jenkins on PR to a branch and Merge to a Branch using JenkinsFile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**How do I kick off a Jenkins job when I send  PR to a branch Develop and also kick off when I merge to that branch.**

With the below code it triggers both the if blocks for PR 
I am trying to use the below code it doesn't work as expected

```
if (env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master') {   if
  (env.BRANCH_NAME.toLowerCase().contains('pr')) {

      try {

        stage 'Checkout Code'
        bogieNode {
          deleteDir()
          echo 'Pulling...' + env.BRANCH_NAME + env.CHANGE_ID
          checkoutCode {}
          project.loadProperties()

          stash 'sources'
        }


      } catch (Exception ex) {
        sendFailureNotifications(
                emailCulprits: true, // emails the suspected commit culprit(s)
                notifySlackChannel: 'xxxxxxx', // send notification to the team's slack channel
        )

        throw ex // re-throw so that the exception bubbles up to the console
      }   } }


      if (env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master') {

        try {

          stage 'Checkout Code'
          bogieNode {
            deleteDir()
            echo 'Hellllooooooooooooooo Pulling...' + env.BRANCH_NAME
            checkoutCode {}
            project.loadProperties()

            stash 'sources'
          }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          sendFailureNotifications(
                  emailCulprits: true, // emails the suspected commit culprit(s)
                  notifySlackChannel: 'xxxxxx', // send notification to the team's slack channel
          )

          throw ex // re-throw so that the exception bubbles up to the console
        }


        }
```

Comment: What is your develop branch name ? Just `Develop` ? Are you using a webhook to trigger your jenkins job ? Your both if blocks contain the same code, what are you trying to do ? Providing some details will help and we can suggest a better way to do what you want.

Comment: I have 2 branches `lgtm `and `master`, 
I do have a webhook setup. 
Want to trigger Jenkins job on PR to `lgtm` and Merge to `lgtm`

Comment: Which scm are you using ?

Comment: Consider looking at Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) with this you can read the webhook and depending on the event whether it is pull request or merge and the branch it came from you can either trigger the jenkins job or ignore the webhook.

Comment: I am using GITHUB

Comment: Got this working by using *env.CHANGE_TARGET*
 ```if (env.CHANGE_TARGET == 'branchname') {
}```